# Javascript, access each object inside one main object - module pattern

Tags: javascript, singleton, javascript-objects

I created small component thats going through all select elements and creating unordered lists from it so that i can style it easily. Everything works just like i wanted. Here is the script:
https://github.com/goranefbl/softdrop

You fire it like this:

```
SoftDrop.init({
  selector:'input_select',
  mobile:true
});
```

and its looping through every "input_select" element and creating new nodes for it. But that is all one single object, and i dont have a way to access for example specific select element, if i want to push an item to it, or to close it with some public method.

For every element, i am adding data-softdrop="i" to it, so this way i could easily target it with:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[data-softdrop='i']")
```

and it works. But if i want to do this from within component, something like this:

```
var selects = SoftDrop.init({
      selector:'input_select',
      mobile:true
    });

selects.data('something').open();
```

How would i go with doing this? I would create some array of objects at the top and during forEach call, push it there, then access it how ? To be able to have public methods on specific select elements.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to create a `data` object inside your component and add each entry as property to this object, e.g. like this:

```
data['something'] = myElement;
```

Then, later, you could access the element again and invoke methods on it, e.g.

```
data['something'].open();
```

Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: Yup, so u mean, that each element could be like data['element_1'], data['element_2'] etc... and accessed like that ? That could create global problem if some other plugin is using data[] ?

Comment: I don't know if this can cause a problem :-) You can always rename `data` to something that does not collide with the other plugin.